# linking gridview column to different textboxes

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

i have a set of textboxes and a gridview data 
i placed the textboxes in a form of a table 
I know how to make the textbox read from the grid view for example if i press the first row in the gridview the data shows in textbox 
but since i have to link the textbox to the gridview column then all the textboxs will read the same info the image shows how i placed the textboxes in form if i table 
lets say in gridview i pressed quantity1 the textboxs all will read quantity1 description1 
i want to be able to press quantity1 and then quantity2 and quantity3 and so on and each will show separately can i do that?

Comment: I suggest adding some *full stops*. It is difficult to understand

Comment: i have a set of textboxes and a gridview data i placed the textboxes in a form of a table.I know how to make the textbox read from the grid view.for example if i press the first row in the gridview the data will show in textbox.but since i have to link the textbox to the gridview column then all the textboxs will read the same data. lets say i have quantity and description textboxes if in gridview, i pressed quantity1 the textboxs all will read quantity1 description1. i want to be able to press quantity1 and then quantity2 and quantity3 and so on and each will show separately can i do that?

Comment: Your title should be *linking datagridview row to different textboxes*, not *column*

Comment: that say you dunno if you cant help me thank you

Comment: How do you fill your datagridview? Can you provide code?

Comment: my datagrid is already filled from my access database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `BindingSource`:

```
Dim bSource As New BindingSource()

bSource.DataSource = 'your DataGridView1 data source
```

and then bind the `textboxes`:

```
textboxQuantity.DataBindings.Add("Text", bSource, "quantity")
textboxDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", bSource, "description")
```